# HOW TO FIND AND PLOT AUC score from TPR and FPR

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, auc

I have True positive rate and False positive rate for different thresholds. Now I need to compute AUC_ROC curve without using sckit-learn library.

```
TPR and FPR values are below:
TPR = [0.0001,0.0002,0.0003,0.0004,0.0005,0.0006,0.0007,0.0008,0.0009,0.001]
FPR = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
```

Can someone please tell how to compute the scores. I used numpy.trapz(TPR,FPR). But the output is weird. Can you suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps, the input arrays should have the boundary points ( (0,0) and (1,1) ) included
for `np.trapz` to work correctly.
Also, having all FPR equal to zero seems strange